# PUT and DELETE method are not working

Tags: php, laravel, get, put

I have some url which are being used through `PUT` and `DELETE` methods these methods are not working on server although these were working on another server.

I have also seen that PUT and DELETE requests are being handled by GET method. Although server is giving error response code.

I am getting `NetworkError: 501 Not Implemented`.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be resolved by enabling `mod_actions` module.

Need to enable `mod_actions` and `mod_rewrite` in Apache, add a <Limit> and <LimitExcept> block to  <Directory> block.

Some time firewall restrict PUT and DELETE methods.